# Multiple databases in an app. How to specify per-model

Tags: django, django-models

I have several models, one of which uses a database on an external user. The database is defined in the settings file. How would I do the following for this model?

```
class ItemMaster(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) # auto-added anyways
    guid = models.CharField(max_length=36, unique=True)

    db = using('avails') # <== use this database
```

Note: the only thing I care about here is being able to do a `get_queryset` query. I don't need a full database router.

Comment: If you want to use Model, most likely you need to define the router as well. I don't know why are you hesitate to do that. It's like 10 lines of code. Or you are not sure how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Shang Wang has pointed out in the comments, using a [database router](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/multi-db/#using-routers) is the best solution.

> Whenever a query needs to know which database to use, it calls the
>   master router, providing a model and a hint (if available). Django
>   then tries each router in turn until a database suggestion can be
>   found. If no suggestion can be found, it tries the current _state.db
>   of the hint instance. If a hint instance wasn’t provided, or the
>   instance doesn’t currently have database state, the master router will
>   allocate the default database.

If you are not keen on using routers, one alternative is to call the `using` on each and every queryset API call to define which database to use.

```
ItemMaster.objects.using('avails').all()
itemmaster.save(using='avails')
itemmaster.delete(using='avails')
```

But this will not be very DRY. A second alternative is to create a custom manager and override each of the methods to add the using('avails') fragments. But this involves writing a lot more code that you would write when using a router.